# Analog oscilloscope trouble

Tags: analog, oscilloscope, probe, crt

I recently purchased an old HP 130B oscilloscope.  While I have experience with old analog oscilloscopes, I have run into an issue with this particular model and before I break anything breaking into it unnecessarily I figured I'd ask.

The main concern is the fact that I am able to get a trace on the screen (a dot even lines when attached to an Arduino outputting 5V periodically,) the scope doesn't seem to move back and forth horizontally unless I input directly into the horizontal input and even then instead of a trace its simply a horizontal line.

Do I need to get another set of probes one for vertical input as well as one for horizontal output probing the same location, or is there a problem internally with the sweep function?

Most of the confusion comes from the fact that this oscilloscope apparently pre-dates BNC connectors like my other oscilloscope had and instead has six banana plug connectors - three for vertical and three for horizontal,  two red and one black with one red and ground tied together with jumpers apparently.

How do I go about probing with this scope or is there something more sinister going on internally?

Comment: so does that mean it should be able to trace the waveform without anything connected to the horizontal inputs just fine?

Comment: ya ive used analog scopes as a matter of fact ive never used a digital scope but the anolog scope i had experience with had bnc connectors and ground was accounted for more or less with the connector so im probably making the banana plug thing into a bigger deal than it is but for some reason i cant seem to get the trace to move horizontally at all except for with the horizontal adjustment knob

Comment: yes it translates horizontally with the knob but without touching the knob the vertical deflection just creates a vertical line with voltage applied to it rather than the left to right sweep im used to seeing on oscilloscopes

Comment: Oh, that's what the wording in your original post was meant to describe. That's X-Y mode it sounds like. It's plotting that channel on the Y-axis against another channel on the X-axis, but since the X-axis channel is zero it just sits there on the same vertical line. Turn off X-Y mode and it will use time for the X-axis instead of another channel.

Comment: and just to be clear the voltage applied to it i have coming from an ardui500no i set up to put out +5v wait 500ms go to 0v wait and repeat just to see if i could see the waveform but it just comes out as a vertical line no matter what i set the sweep time to

Comment: For fun you can get a potentiometer, wire it up as a divider connect it it to the other channel and sweep it up and down. Or connect a sawtooth function generator up to it if you have one.

Comment: well when i apply the same voltage to the horizontal inputs it makes it into a horizontal line rather than vertical and if i move the horizontal adjustment back and forth kinda fast i can almost see the waveform which made me think everything was working internally except whatever tells it to sweep so i started playing with the triggering and nothing seemed to fix it

Comment: That definitely sounds like X-Y mode. If the control to get it out of X-Y mode isn't working then something is wrong with the scope. Here is the manual if you need it: http://hparchive.com/Manuals/HP-130B-Manual-SNprefix-201.pdf

Comment: ya ive gone through the manual and set it up how it walks through the dc balance adjustments and everything seemed in order until i tried to actually view a waveform and it refuses to scan accross the screen. i think im going to end up having to open it up and take a look because it seems like something is wrong internally

Answer (score 4):

As @DKNguyen suggests, make sure the switch is set to "internal sweep" as shown in the [manual](http://hparchive.com/Manuals/HP-130B-BR-Manual.pdf):

[image]

x5 gives you magnified (in the X dimension) sweeps, normally leave it at x1

---

If that's not working, then something is wrong with the horizontal sweep generator. It could be a switch or a vacuum tube could be kaput.

[Here](http://hparchive.com/Manuals/HP-130B-Manual-SNprefix-201.pdf) is the service manual that has complete schematics. Unlike some more modern oscilloscopes, some of which contain hybrid circuits that are simply not available without cannibalizing another old scope, this one should be completely repairable.

Be careful if poking around inside, there are plenty of potentially lethal high-voltage nodes in there.

Comment: Oh so on analog scopes it's called internal/external sweep, not X-Y mode.

Comment: @DKNguyen It's called X-Y mode on all three analog scopes I have at hand. X-Y tends to be a bit disappointing on digital scopes.

Comment: i  tried that but it was just a vertical line about 5v high when i connect the probes to the arduino with my last  scope it would be a horizontal line at the voltage level when i applied a dc voltage which is what's been throwing me off

Comment: The only times I've used X-Y mode I had a $20k digital scope beside me so not really sure how that compares since I don't have anything to compare it to, another digital or analog. Seemed to work fine. But I was doing B-H hysteresis loops so I needed the integral function on the digital scope anyways.

Comment: @Shittykorean4banger Read the manual. It has a procedure for each mode you want to use the scope in. So use either the "internal sweep-internal synch" or "internal sweep-external synch" instructions,

Comment: If the internal sweep isn't working then something is broken. Maybe a switch, maybe something else.